# Obtener el índice asociativo correspondiente al mayor valor

Tags: php, array

He hecho un array asociativo en PHP y quiero sacar la nota más alta y ver a qué nombre corresponde esa nota. Sin embargo, algo estoy haciendo mal.

```
<?php 

    $alumnos=array("Pepe" => 8, "Eduardo" => 5, "Hans" => 9, "Sara" => 7, "Vero" => 5);

    $mayor=$alumnos["Pepe"];
    $i=0;
    foreach ($alumnos as $indice=>$valores) {
        if ($valores > $mayor) {
            $mayor = $alumnos[$indice];
            $nombre=key($alumnos);
        }
    }
    echo "El alumno con mayor nota es: $mayor y su nombre es: $nombre";
 ?>
```

En este caso, me devuelve:

> El alumno con mayor nota es: 9 y su nombre es: Sara.

***¿Cómo hago para que salga Hans? Gracias.***

Comment: Hola, amigo te recomiendo que pases por aquí: [tour] y que te leas estos artículos: [help/dont-ask], [help/on-topic], [help/behavior] y que arregles tu pregunta mirando este articulo: [mcve] tambien puedes pedir ayuda en: [chat]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No es gran cosa, solo debes darle `$indice` al `$nombre`.
Es más, debes pasar el `$valores` también, por que estás obteniendo el valor con el `foreach`, es ilógico obtenerlo manualmente luego.

De este modo, la salida será:

> El alumno con mayor nota es: 9 y su nombre es: Hans

```
<?php

$alumnos = array("Pepe" => 8, "Eduardo" => 5, "Hans" => 9, "Sara" => 7, "Vero" => 5);

$mayor = $alumnos["Pepe"];
foreach ($alumnos as $indice => $valores) {
    if ($valores > $mayor) {
        $mayor = $valores;
        $nombre = $indice;
    }
}
echo "El alumno con mayor nota es: $mayor y su nombre es: $nombre";
```

Comment: Madre mía, no lo veía!! Muchas gracias :)

Comment: Era algo sencillo, nada más. Recuerda marcar la respuesta para que la publicación quede completa

Comment: @Serzox si la respuesta del compañero resuelve tu duda, es conveniente que marques la respuesta como solución. saludos.

Answer (score 2):

Yo lo hice de esta forma usando la función **max** para seleccionar el valor mas alto del array y desde ahí seleccione los valores correspondientes a los que necesitaba:

```
<?php 

    $alumnos=array("Pepe" => 8, "Eduardo" => 5, "Hans" => 9, "Sara" => 7, "Vero" => 5);

    $mayor = max($alumnos);

    foreach ($alumnos as $indice=>$valores) {
        if ($valores == $mayor) {
            $nombre=$indice;  
        }
    }
    echo "El alumno con mayor nota es: $mayor y su nombre es: $nombre";
 ?>
```

De esta forma logré que me saliera **(El alumno con mayor nota es: 9 y su nombre es: Hans)**.

Comment: Si te pones a usar MAX, lo estás usando muy mal bro... por que estás destruyendo el IF en este caso. Si ya conoces el mayor valor, no tienes que hacer el IF, menos estar reasignando $mayor con el mismo valor.

Comment: @Excorpion use el **if** para sacar mas rápido el nombre de la persona y de cierta forma que mi codigo coincida con el de  **Serzox**, ¿pero entonces mi respuesta esta mal? o ¿qué debo hacer? ya que esta sería mi primera pregunta respondida y realmente intento ayudar al sitio.

Comment: Bueno, pues el que si te sobra acá, es $mayor = $mayor, no tiene sentido alguno ese.

Comment: Cierto ese no lo noté, ya edité mi pregunta :)

Comment: @DavidFloresGarcía no es pregunta, es respuesta ;)

Answer (score 2):

el problema es que estas implementando el método `key` mal, error de lógica.

***nota:*** estas implementando un bucle (foreach) que si es funcional pero no necesario. desde mi punto de vista de manejo de recurso.

Se ha demostrado que `array_flip` es 2.5 veces mas rápido que `foreach` [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56909572/17161735)

yo implementaría el uso de `max` y `array_flip`

es bastante sencillo, solo debes extraer el valor máximo del array con max;
y luego intercambiar llaves y valores con array_flip; una vez esto, el valor de max lo usas como índice en el nuevo array:

**Ejemplo:**

```php
$alumnos=array("Pepe" => 8, "Eduardo" => 5, "Hans" => 9, "Sara" => 7, "Vero" => 5);

$mayor = max($alumnos); //extraes el valor máximo

$newarray = array_flip($alumnos); //inviertes el array; tus valores ahora son indices

//echo $newarray[$mayor]; //usas el valor máximo como índice

echo "El alumno con mayor nota es: $mayor y su nombre es: ".$newarray[$mayor];
```

**output:**

> El alumno con mayor nota es: 9 y su nombre es: Hans

Ejecución: [Link](https://wtools.io/php-sandbox/b7lo)

Documentacion [max](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.max.php) y [array_flip](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-flip.php):